# Is there a Hilbert's list for $21$st century?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

David Hilbert gave his famous list of $23$ unsolved problems presented in Paris in $1900$. Most of the problems are fully/partially resolved, some are still open (RH etc) and some are impossible to prove. Now if some mathematician has to present a similar list for $21$st century, what unsolved problems will definitely added to that list? What are the candidates? Can anyone suggest a few such problems?

Comment: How about the millenium problems?

Answer (score 2):

There already is at least one such list, compiled by Stephen Smale. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smale's_problems)

Comment: to the anonymous downvoter: would you mind explaining what's wrong with this answer?